# Discrepancy in AutoCAD Architecture:Surface( Interior Wall ) Coordinates received from Space Data Is Not Matching Original Wall Coordinates

Tags: .net, autocad-plugin

We are currently working with space data in AutoCAD Architecture and have encountered a discrepancy in the coordinates of Surface( Interior Wall) Coordinates compared to the original wall coordinates. Despite both being walls, the coordinates do not align as expected. We suspect this might be due to each entity having its own Entity Coordinate System (ECS).

Could someone shed light on why this discrepancy might be happening and provide guidance on how to effectively handle or reconcile these differences? Any insights, explanations, or suggested approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

We were expecting that Space data should hold information is all entity enclosed in it like walls, door, windows.. etc. but it is having surface data as interior wall type and its coordinates are not matching with actual wall data